# i want to show value in view table when recived data from controller in php MVC

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I am trying to show data in view table.but it's show me some problem.how could solved the problem. this my code

main Controller:

```
public function view($view,$data =[]) 
{
    require_once"../app/views/".$view.".php";
}
```

Home Controller method:

```
public function index() { 
    $array=User::select("name")->get(); 
    $this->view('home/index',$array);//` load from controller view method 
}
```

view table :

```
<tr> 
    <TD><?echo $data['name'] ?></TD> 
    <TD><?echo $data['email'] ?></TD> 
</tr>
```

correct value not found. Please help me.

Comment: could you format the code into a code block?

Comment: Could be more specific then `some problem`? Are you getting an error message? For future posting see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.

Comment: Okay, first: are you using a framework? Second: what is the value of `$data`? Third: It's bad practice to uppercase HTML tags, e.g: `<TD>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<tr> 
<TD><?echo $data['name'] ?></TD> 
<TD><?echo $data['email'] ?></TD> 
</tr>
```

see your code? Look at it very closely. you merged the `<?` PHP tag with the `echo` function.

It should be:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $data['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['email'] ?></td>
</tr>
```

or for shorthand:

```
<tr>
    <td><?= $data['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $data['email'] ?></td>
</tr>
```